# Обход массива змейкой

Tags: массивы, алгоритм, циклы, динамические-массивы

Ребят привет, мне нужна ваша помощь. Нужно сделать вывод массива обходом змейкой размерами n, m и с указанием направления. Со вложенными циклами и я умею делать. Не надо карать.

Есть такой момент,

Условия следующие :

1. ИСПОЛЬЗОВАТЬ ТОЛЬКО ОДИН ЦИКЛ
2. НЕ ИСПОЛЬЗОВАТЬ УСЛОВИЯ

Важен сам алгоритм, язык не важен. Благодарю заранее

Answer (score 1):

Записываем математически... Можно через `abs` - было бы чуть проще, но мы пойдем трудным путем:

```
for(int k = 0; k < n*m; ++k )
    cout << a[k/n][k%n+k/n%2*(n-1-2*(k%n))] << " ";
```

Полный код с проверкой - https://ideone.com/ectuBK

Comment: разъясните пожалуйста как вы вывели эту формулу, я хочу понять..

Comment: Ну смотрите - k/n (деление целое) - это просто номер строки, тут все просто. Дальше - по строке - если идем слева направо (по нечетной строке, т.е. `k/n%2 == 0`) - то номер k%n, по нечетной - назад: `n-1-k%n` (посмотрите и поймете сами). А тееперь просто объединяем их в одно целое.

Answer (score 0):

Вспоминаем математику :)

```
f1 = Int((x - 1) / m) + 1

f2 = (x - 1) Mod m + 1
```

Где `x` - шаг цикла

Для `n` меняем функции местами

В `VBA` это выглядит приблизительно так:

```
Sub Main_()
    Dim a()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Const n As Long = 4, m As Long = 3

    ReDim a(1 To n, 1 To m)

    For i = 1 To n
        For j = 1 To m
            a(i, j) = i * 10 + j
        Next j
    Next i

    Call test_(a, n, m)
End Sub
'-----------------------------------'
Sub test_(a(), n As Long, m As Long)
    Dim lCnt As Long, i As Long

    lCnt = n * m

    For i = 1 To lCnt
        Debug.Print a(Int((i - 1) / m) + 1, (i - 1) Mod m + 1)
    Next i

    For i = 1 To lCnt
        Debug.Print a((i - 1) Mod n + 1, Int((i - 1) / n) + 1)
    Next i
End Sub
```